# Getting list of scores from a certain stage and level

Tags: php, mysql

For my game I am trying to include an online score system.
For my score system to work i want to get a list of scores from my database.
But since I'm not that experienced with mysql statementes, I have no clue how to write a query for what i want.

The structure of my table: http://prntscr.com/6z45bv

In my query i want to return all the colums in my my table "scores"

```
    SELECT * from scores
```

with only the the stage and level given with a GET request in php

```
    WHERE stage = [number] AND level = [number]
```

with my request I would like to get the highest single score from all devices sorted from highest to lowest. the devices are stored in the "deviceid" column

The highest score from a device is the highest amount of "blastpoints"(descending) with the highest amount of "time"(descending). Where the highest amount of blastpoints are the most important.

Here is an example of what i would want as a result:

```
    id, name,      stage,  level,  blastpoints,  time, badge, deviceid

    5,  "bob"      2       3       5             7123  true   "asdakjhe"
    1,  "rick"     2       3       5             6321  false  "3jkhasdl3"
    8,  "melissa"  2       3       4             8565  false  "nlk43h2l"
    2,  "steven"   2       3       4             5678  true   "342jhlad"
    3,  "freddy"   2       3       3             6721  false  "1lk23jl1"
    7,  "hank"     2       3       2             5600  false  "41asdg42"
```

In this example i retrieved the scores from stage 2, level 3. as you can see the blastpoints are descending and it only finds the highest score of a single deviceid.

The scores are set up that a player with a certain deviceid can upload as many scores as he wants in the table.

I hope I gave enough information, for further questions please comment. And thanks in advance.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Could you link me an example of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing Augwa's query for a while, I figured out it was not working.
I did some trial and error myself and found the correct query.

```
SELECT A.name,A.blastpoints,A.time,A.badge,A.deviceid
FROM (SELECT B.id,B.name,B.blastpoints,B.time,B.badge,B.deviceid
    FROM scores B
    WHERE B.stage = 0
    AND B.level =  0
    ORDER BY blastpoints DESC, time DESC) A
GROUP BY A.deviceid
ORDER BY A.blastpoints DESC, A.time DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

In SQL you can use `ORDER BY` to sort your results. In this case, since you would need:

```
ORDER BY blastpoints DESC, time DESC
```

We use `DESC` for descending order. That way the largest scores appear at the top. The order in which you specify column names in `ORDER BY` matters as well, which is why we specify *blastpoints* first and *time* second, as per your example. You can read more on [`ORDER BY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx), too.

Putting it all together:

```
SELECT * FROM scores
WHERE stage = [number] AND level = [number]
ORDER BY blastpoints DESC, time DESC
```

Comment: Okay this seems nice, but can i also add an "GROUP BY deviceid" at the end? so it only gives the highest score per deviceid?

Comment: You would add that to the preexisting `ORDER BY` clause. For example: `ORDER BY deviceid, blastpoints DESC, time DESC` would give you the highest scores/times sorted for deviceid. The order does matter and will affect the sort.

Comment: If you want all the high scores, my answer works as it is. If you want just top scores per device, look at Augwa's answer below. It needs to take the time field into account, but it certainly is workable.

Comment: I found the correct query after some testing, posted it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is group by. Group by works on uniqueness so there are certain fields that you can't group by as they will simply cause problems. The id field for instance you could not do a group by, but you can get the min(), max() of it.

The below query will show you the top scores for each device on each level and stage.

```
SELECT
    stage,
    level,
    deviceid,
    max(blastpoints) score
FROM
    scores
GROUP BY
    stage,
    level
    deviceid
ORDER BY
    level ASC,
    stage ASC,
    score DESC,
    deviceid
```

This query should allow you to consider time as well.

```
SELECT
    min(s.id) id,
    s.stage,
    s.level,
    hs.score,
    s.time,
    s.badge,
    s.deviceid
FROM
    scores s
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            stage,
            level,
            deviceid,
            max(blastpoints) score
        FROM
            scores
        GROUP BY
            stage,
            level
            deviceid
    ) hs ON
        hs.deviceid = s.deviceid
        AND hs.score = s.blastpoints
        AND hs.stage = s.stage
        AND hs.level = s.level
WHERE
    s.stage = :stage
    AND s.level = :level
GROUP BY
    s.level,
    s.stage,
    hs.score,
    s.time,
    s.badge,
    s.deviceid
ORDER BY
    s.level ASC,
    s.stage ASC,
    hs.score DESC,
    s.time,
    s.deviceid
```

Comment: Unsure if you want to order by score DESC, as I think scores for levels tend to differ and thus are incomparable. I like everything else here though, and I think this is the answer closest to what the original poster wants.

Comment: true, perhaps the score should come after the level and stage.

Comment: i fixed a comma at the group by, but it still gives the error: Column 'stage' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: I updated the query, I forgot to add the table alias infront of each of the where columns.

Comment: could you tell me why you used: "min(s.id) id" at the first SELECT?

Comment: it's to avoid duplicates. Lets say you have a device that has the same score for the same stage/level. You can't add it to the group by because it is unique. In this case it would give you the id of the row that was first recorded. If you don't care about the id, then you can just remove this from the select.

Comment: After testing this query for a while, it was not showing the correct data. After some trial and error I finally made a query that displays the correct data. Ill post it as the correct answer to my question(couldn't have done it without the help i got here).